# How can I have template in "Create Task" (for bug reporting) in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I want to have a template when people from support group want to add bugs.

Here is an example (https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/new) in GitHub that I want to implement in Phabricator if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phabricator supports customizing forms, including the 'create task' form. There are a couple of ways to go about it and they are covered in [the documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/forms/).

The simplest way to customize forms is to provide default values in the URL for the links you provide, for example, say you link to the bug submission form from your documentation. You can supply the template text as part of the link itself. This can result in long ugly URLs but that can be masked by using a url shortening service.

I'll use [Wikimedia's phabricator](http://phabricator.wikimedia.org) as an example of how this works. If you want to make a link to the create task form with your template text pre-filled, you construct a url like the following:

`https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/?description=[insert template text here]`

The other way to do this, which doesn't require you to store the template text in the url, is to edit the form and specify a default value for the description field. Editing forms is covered in the phabricator upstream documentation so I won't go into that, instead I refer you to the documentation section under the heading [creating new forms](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/forms/#creating-new-forms).